# Can I check for initial or not equal values with line_exists?

Tags: abap

ABAP 7.40 added the `line_exists( ... )` predicate function to analyse internal tables. But is there any way I can **check for the presence of a line where a particular column is initial or different from a target value?**

For instance, how can I check for a line with an initial Material column like the third line in this table?

```
Document        Country     Material    
9001287         US          198572111
9001296         FR          160023941       
9001297         EG                      
9001299         DK          873001102
```

I could check for Danish entries with `line_exists( lt_itab[ Country = 'DK' ] )` and `line_exists( lt_itab[ Material = '' ] )` is valid but neither `<>` nor `NE` seem to be accepted. There also seems to be no way to check for lines where the country isn't 'FR' for instance?

If there's no way to do this with `line_exists`, what would be the most condensed alternative approach?

Comment: As Suncatcher replied, `line_exists` works like `READ TABLE` so only `=` is supported. Note that you may use line_exists with several components: `line_exists( lt_itab[ country = 'DK' material = ' ' ] )`

Answer (score 4):

LOOP is one way to check, I don't know if there is anything better:

```
LOOP AT itab
     TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS
     WHERE country NE 'FR'.
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.
IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
" line exists
ELSE.
" line does not exist
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.

**line_exists** is simple predicate function which accepts only table expressions `tab[ a = b ]`. And, as we know, table expressions is simply a new syntax for READ TABLE, nothing more. All rules and constraints including allowed comparison type are applied to expressions as well.

Check [H. Keller's blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/22/abap-news-for-release-740-new-internal-table-functions/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late. But now you can do the following:

```
xsdbool( line_exists( lt_itab[ Country = 'DK' ] ) ) = abap_false
```

Comment: Tested and works!

Answer (score 1):

A little bit later, here's another (shorter) way to do the same thing as in Andreas' answer:

```
IF NOT line_exists( lt_itab[ country = 'DK' ] ).
```

However, this tests whether there is *no line equal* to DK in the table. It does **NOT** test whether there is *any line that is unequal* to DK.
If you want the second thing, you have to resort to LOOP as József pointed out. Or you could compress it into one line like this:

```
IF lines( VALUE type( FOR x IN lt_itab WHERE ( country <> 'DK' ) ( x ) ) ) > 0.
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use `VALUE #( )`, so you have to put in the type of `lt_itab`.

If country is the primary key, another possibility is

```
IF lines( FILTER #( lt_itab WHERE country <> 'DK' ) ) > 0.
```

and if country is only the secondary key, you could do

```
IF lines( FILTER #( lt_itab USING KEY country WHERE country <> 'DK' ) ) > 0.
```