# Checking all rows of itab against a condition via REDUCE?

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, abap, until-loop

In order to check whether all entries of an internal table `lt_itab` meet a condition COND, I would like to use REDUCE statement. The loop of course needs to terminate once a line violating COND occurs. The second code block further down seems to work but appears to me like a slight abuse of the iteration index. *Are you aware of a better/more transparent solution within the REDUCE syntax?* Is it possible to work with a structure (integer, boolean) for the iteration variable? The `INDEX INTO` option seems not to work with REDUCE. Compatibility to kernel-release 753 (or lower) would be nice.

Here is my Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) which passes syntax check only if `lvr_flag_allowed =  abap_false OR` is commented out (viz -> `"lvr_flag_allowed =  abap_false OR`):

```
DATA: lt_itab         TYPE TABLE OF i,
      rv_flag_allowed TYPE boole_d.

lt_itab = VALUE #( ( 2 ) ( 1 ) ( -1 ) ( 5 ) ).

IF lt_itab IS NOT INITIAL.
  rv_flag_allowed = REDUCE #( INIT lvr_flag_allowed = abap_true
                              FOR lvf_idx = 1 UNTIL lvr_flag_allowed =  abap_false OR
                                                    lvf_idx > lines( lt_itab )
                              NEXT lvr_flag_allowed = xsdbool( lt_itab[ lvf_idx ] < 0 ) ).
ENDIF.

RETURN.
```

Currently it gives this syntax check message (its ID is `MESSAGEG[M`):

> The variable "LVR_FLAG_ALLOWED" cannot be used here.

Do you know the technical reason why this does not work? The [SAP documentation on REDUCE - Reduction Operator](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-us/index.htm?file=abenfor_conditional.htm) only states

> Usually the expression expr (after THEN) and the termination condition log_exp (after UNTIL or WHILE) depend on the iteration variable var.

Hence a workaround MRE came to my mind while writing this down:

```
DATA: lt_itab       TYPE TABLE OF i,
*      rv_flag_allowed TYPE boole_d,
      rv_last_index TYPE i.

lt_itab = VALUE #( ( 2 ) ( 1 ) ( -22 ) ( 5 ) ( 7 ) ( 4 ) ).

IF lt_itab IS NOT INITIAL.
  rv_last_index = REDUCE #( INIT lvr_last_index = 0
                              FOR lvf_idx = 1 THEN COND #( WHEN lt_itab[ lvf_idx ] < 0
                                                                THEN 0
                                                                ELSE lvf_idx + 1 )
                                              UNTIL lvf_idx = 0 OR
                                                    lvf_idx > lines( lt_itab )
                              NEXT lvr_last_index = lvr_last_index + 1 ).
ENDIF.

RETURN.
```

It makes "double" use of the iteration index and returns `rv_last_index = 3`. I'm returning an integer now rather than a boolean in order to check the correct abort result. Does this seem correct to you?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback and improvement suggestions (beyond the classical while/until loops ;-)) !

Comment: The only possibility to exit at any time is to throw an exception using `COND` or `SWITCH` and word `THROW`, but then it won't return any value. You can ask SAP at their support Web site why they designed it this way.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539819/can-i-check-for-initial-or-not-equal-values-with-line-exists

Comment: unlikely you will avoid LOOPing, however you can reduce the number of iterations via [grouping by](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abaploop_at_itab_group_by.htm) field you are checking on

Comment: Thank you @SandraRossi for your input and moreover the very instructive improvements on my original post! `THROW` probably could be combined with `TRY ... CATCH ... ENDTRY` to set the final result. But I guess that's not best practice either.

Comment: You can't "set the final result" with `THROW`, as I said before "it won't return any value." (it will raise an exception instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would actually like to express this using `line_exists`, unfortunately [table expressions only support equality comparisons](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_exp_itab_line.htm) though (and sadly not `<`):

```
"                                              invalid syntax v
DATA(some_negative) = xsdbool( line_exists( values[ table_line < 0 ] ) ).
```

A slightly more verbose but working variant would be using a `LOOP AT` with an immediate [`EXIT.`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapexit_loop.htm) (yes, this is not "modern syntax", though still very readable IMO):

```
DATA(some_negative) = abap_false.
LOOP AT values WHERE table_line < 0 TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS.
  some_negative = abap_true.
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.
```

I don't think that REDUCE is the right tool for the job, as it is supposed to comprehend the table into one value (in other languages there is also no short-circuit, e.g. the `.reduce` in JS, though they have other methods for this purpose like `.some` and `.every` and the alike). If the number of truthy rows is low, not having short circuiting for them might be acceptable, and this `REDUCE` statement would at least not visit falsy rows through the additional [`WHERE ( ... )` clause](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor_cond.htm):

```
DATA(some_negative) = REDUCE abap_bool(
  INIT result = abap_false
  FOR entry IN values
   WHERE ( table_line < 0 )
   NEXT result = abap_true
).
```

Comment: Many thanks to @JonasWilms for your extensive input. In my given context, I have an itab of object references. The check is actually a method call `table_line->check( )` rather than `table_line < 0`. Apparently I should have been more precise in my original post as my MRE was too simple.
But even with that in mind, `loop at itab assigning <fieldsymbol>` seems more readable and (for now) the way to go.

For the sake of completeness: `REDUCE` can also be used with a structured data type for the iteration expression. One could use a boolean to store the check result.